# Adding Samesite cookie to ajs_user_id

Tags: asp.net, openid-connect, owin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOnI1.png)

I am using owin authentication but not able to set the same site cookie to NONE for ajs_user_id and ajs-anonymoususer_id

I have tried using web config to set it . but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set a samesite cookie with none, then it also must be set with the secure attribute, and you must do this over HTTPS, not HTTP.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic:
[Debugging cookie problems](https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/)

Comment: Thanks it works for me after adding secure attribute